# concat every field in pig?

Tags: group-by, concatenation, apache-pig

I am currently trying to create a concatenating string for each group. This string should be the concatenation of all the occurrences of the field.

For the moment my code looks like :

```
grouped = GROUP a by group_field;

b = FOREACH grouped {
    unique_field = DISTINCT myfield;
    tupl = TOTUPLE(unique_field) ; 
    FOREACH tupl GENERATE group as id, CONCAT( ? ) as my_new_string;
}
```

The thing is I absolutely do not know for each group the number of distinct fields or what they contains. I don't know how what to do to replace the `?` and make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TOTUPLE`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#totuple) is not doing what you are expecting, it is making a one element tuple where that one element is the bag of `unique_field`.

Also, [`CONCAT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#concat) only takes two things to concat and they must be explicitly defined.  Let's say that you have a schema like `A: {A1: chararray, A2: chararray, A3: chararray}` and you want to concatinate all fields together.  You will have to do this (which is obviously not ideal): `CONCAT(CONCAT(A1, A2), A3)`.

Anyways, this problem can be easily solved with a [python UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html#python-udfs).

**myudfs.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema('concated: string')
def concat_bag(BAG):
    return ''.join(BAG)
```

This UDF would be used in your script like:

```
Register 'myudfs.py' using jython as myfuncs;

grouped = GROUP a by group_field;

b = FOREACH grouped {
    unique_field = DISTINCT myfield;
    GENERATE group as id, myfuncs.concat_bag(unique_field);
}
```

I just noticed the `FOREACH tupl GENERATE ...` line.  That is not valid syntax.  The last statement in a nested `FOREACH` should be a `GENERATE`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed later the FOREACH tup1 is incorrect. Do you know approximately what would be the performance of the python udf ? I mean is that the best language for UDFs ?

Comment: @Scratch It all compiles down to Java byte code, so Java and Python UDFs should have very similar speeds.  I always use Python for UDFs because they are significantly easier to write (seriously, check out the Java UDF section) and understand.

Comment: @outputSchema('concated: string') should be @outputSchema('concated: chararray'), at least for me.